# How to get where clause to return rows where value of one column is prior to other column date but also still return ones where value is null

Tags: mysql

I am trying to build report pulling all rows where the columns of 2 of the tables billing.billed_date or indiv_response.date_submitted that show date later then say 10/20/2021 but then also want to narrow that result down to show only rows where the billed_date is prior to the date_submitted and leave any rows where the date submitted also might be blank or null.
so for my initial where clause i had it as
`WHERE billing.billed_date >= '2021-10-20' OR indiv_responses.date_submitted >= '2021-10-20'`
and this gives desired initial result of showing all rows where either billed_date or date_submitted are greater than or = to the given date. If i then add an AND to limit to rows
`(billings.billed_date >= '2021-10-25'OR indiv_responses.date_submitted >= '2021-10-25') AND billings.billed_date < indiv_responses.date_submitted`
where the billed_date is < date_submitted this pares it down further but i lose all the entries where no date was put into date_submitted yet. is there some way to word the where clause here to show the rows where billed_date is < date_submitted and also show the date_submitted that are null

As an example these are few rows that return for billed_date after 10/20/2021 but there wasnt a submitted_date yet. but if i try to add the billed_date is < date_submitted i lose all these rows ,since null value is not < an actual date.

```
FILE #              Billed Date Submitted Date
ALL-B32224552       10/28/2021  null
GRR-BSD344335       10/28/2021  null
PPW-GRE349955       10/28/2021  null
GOW-QAS234543       10/28/2021  null
FSC-HKL334450       10/28/2021  null
```

So is there some way in the where clause to do this ? or do i need to have to look at some subquery or something ? just hoping the sql experts might know a simple solution im not seeing

thanks for any help
here is example of query running, this returns all the rows that meet that where clause, but if i try to pare down after that  to just show from those results ones that billed_date is < submitted_date i lose all the rows where submitted date is currently null and we want to keep those

```
    SELECT
  dd.file_acceptance,
  billing.billed_date,
  indiv_responses.date_submitted
FROM ds
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dd
    ON ds.dd_id = dd.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN billing
    ON ds.billing_id = billing.id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN indiv_responses
    ON indiv_responses.ds_id = ds.id
WHERE (billing.billed_date >= '2021-10-25'OR indiv_responses.date_submitted >= '2021-10-25')
```

Comment: Could you please provide your intents?

Comment: sorry, what is an intents ? just not clear, if you can clarify i can try and provide thx

Comment: I mean tries, your queries

Comment: i added the query above thx

Comment: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Please clarify your date datatype. Why date is `MM/DD/YYYY` format in your data sample but your query is filtering standard data format of `YYYY-MM-DD`.? If your table really stores date as  `MM/DD/YYYY`, then of course you won't get any result when you use date manipulation filtering on it. Otherwise, if your table data actually stores standard date format, you may want to consider defining a `DEFAULT` date instead of `DEFAULT NULL`. Probably set it to `1900-01-01` as default. If not, you probably can use functions like `IFNULL()` to replace the `NULL` values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like adding another condition as following will do

```
AND ( indiv_responses.date_submitted IS NULL OR indiv_responses.date_submitted > billing.billed_date )
```

so that `date_submitted` is either `NULL` or after `billed_date`

Comment: I think that might work, thanks will run some more tests tomorrow.

Comment: That worked, thanks